# Inserts into a SQL database table that has a varbinary(max) column can be slow

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, database-performance, varbinary

We have the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spMergePPObjectBlobProperty]
(
    @values dbo.udtPPObjectBlobProperty readonly
)
as
begin

    begin try

        declare @updatetime datetime
        set @updatetime = GetUTCDate()

        merge tblPPObjectBlobProperty as t
        using (select * from @values) as s
        on t.InsertionId = s.InsertionId and t.PropertyMapNameId = s.PropertyMapNameId
        when matched then 
            update set UpdateTime = @updatetime, [Value] = s.BlobValue, UpdateId = s.UpdateId
        when not matched then
            insert (PropertyMapNameId, Value, UpdateId, UpdateTime, InsertionId) 
                values(s.PropertyMapNameId, s.BlobValue, s.UpdateId, @updatetime, s.InsertionId)
        option (loop join);

    end try
    begin catch

        declare @errormessage varchar(256)

        -- Get the error message
        select @errormessage = ERROR_MESSAGE()

        -- Raise an error and return
        raiserror('Error updating entries in the tblPPObjectBlobProperty Table. %s', 16, 1, @errormessage)

    end catch

end
```

Occasionally, this sp can take a few seconds to run with only several rows to insert. Other times it is extremely fast.

We have a number of these sps and this is the only one that appears to be slow sometimes and it is the only one that inserts into a table with a varbinary(max) column.

The type used here is defined as follows:

```
    CREATE TYPE [dbo].[udtPPObjectBlobProperty] AS TABLE(
    [InsertionId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [PropertyMapNameId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BlobValue] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [UpdateId] [bigint] NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [InsertionId] ASC,
    [PropertyMapNameId] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO
```

Can this stored procedure be optimised in any way?

Comment: please share the code of function used in parameter section

Comment: Have you looked at the wait stats? When this seems slow. Sometimes the Sql server service account is not granted the perform volume maintenance rights. Which can impact the speed of the data file growth. But sharing wait stats can help identify the issue.

Comment: Type definition has been added. I will look into the wait stats.